# ServiceStack IServiceClient throws "<request DTO> is not of type IList<>" when running on iOS device

Tags: xamarin.ios, servicestack

A ServiceStack service client invocation (that works fine on desktop and iOS simulator) crashes when run on iOS devices. The service is the minimal "Hello" from ServiceStack's docs/samples:

```
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse> {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse {
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

I'm invoking it like this:

```
IServiceClient client = new JsonApiClient("https://foobar.com/");   
Hello request = new Hello { Name = "World!" };
var response = await client.ApiAsync(request);
```

(Note that the service URI is irrelevant here, as the crash occurs on device before the service is actually called.)

Attempting to run this in Debug mode on an iPhone from Visual Studio Mac OS 17.5.4, the `ApiAsync()` call throws `ArgumentException` from within ServiceStack.Text:

```
System.ArgumentException    "Type ServiceTest.Hello is not of type IList<>"

   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteLists`2[[ServiceTest.Hello, ServiceTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer, ServiceStack.Text, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].GetWriteFn() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/WriteLists.cs:line 497
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteLists`2[[ServiceTest.Hello, ServiceTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer, ServiceStack.Text, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]..cctor() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/WriteLists.cs:line 483
```

[image]

The test case is a minimal net7.0-ios (Xamarin.iOS) single-project solution. I've tried:

- .NET 6 instead of .NET 7
- `JsonServiceClient` & `JsonHttpClient` instead of `JsonApiClient`
- Other `IServiceClient` methods, e.g. `PostAsync()` instead of `ApiAsync()`
- Different iOS devices with different iOS major versions
- Newest and older releases of ServiceStack (6.8.0, 6.7.0, 6.6.0, 6.5.0, 6.0.2)
- Various messing around with Xamarin linker settings, specifying "linkskip" for the SS assemblies, [Preserve] attribute on DTO classes
- Some of these changes resulted in different crashes, but all of them seem related to AOT

Any ideas? Is there some magic needed for ServiceStack.[Text] to work on iOS devices?

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate, and frankly a bit surprising, but ServiceStack informs me by email that this scenario is unsupported.

From `team@servicestack.net`:

> This issue looks due to Xamarin AOT issues which isn't a supported
> platform.

And:

> It used to work with older versions of Xamarin but their newer Xamarin
> implementations appears to have since broken the limited support they
> had for generic reflection in their earlier iOS AOT implementations,
> it doesn't look likely they will resolve these issues in future
> versions of Xamarin that given that Microsoft plans on ending support
> for Xamarin on May 1, 2024.